# Serial Comma Example

Tags: commas

> A child improves their skills in aiming, throwing, catching and bouncing a ball, and will kick a ball with force and acuracy by using their whole body.

Are the commas in the right places?

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is clear and understandable. However, without additional context the reader may be wondering what you are talking about.  For example

> As a child's development improves, ...

would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, that's fine.

Longer answer: There's a raging debate about what's called the "Oxford comma": When you have a list with three or more elements, should you put a comma before the "and" on the last element. Some say the correct construction is "throwing, catching and bouncing", as you have. Others add a comma and write "throwing, catching, and bouncing". If you're writing for an organization that has a style sheet, follow the style sheet. Otherwise, take your pick. It doesn't make a lot of difference.